# How can i get Express.js to serve after being Webpacked?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack

I'm trying to get a system together for transpiling my Node server (Express in this case) down, much in the same way as my client side scripts - with webpack.

The Express server is pretty basic. I import some node_modules and some local, relative files. Webpack seems to have no trouble parsing everything, importing the relative files and simply require()'ing node_modules (thanks to externals).

However, when I run the server (with `node server.js`) after webpacking, it get an error trying to access my index.html.

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/public/index.html'
    at Error (native)
```

The server reports it is listening on 3000, but every attempted access logs this error and displays it in browser. I'm sending a premade HTML file with the following:

```
res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
```

I've searched and discovered people using the `babel-cli` for just using Babel (and presets) alone to just run that on designated Node code, but then I cannot resolve any of the module paths.

Has anyone else successfully transpiled a Node server application and gotten it to actually serve? Should I use a different function to serving my client-side? Should I be going about this in a different way rather than Webpack?

Comment: I'm not a webpack expert but: Why do you want to transpile your `server.js` using webpack at all? What is the advantage? I'd imagine you'd, at most, want to transpile the JS that is served to the client by `server.js`, but not `server.js` itself.

Comment: Well, valid question. The packing isn't so much what I want, but rather the transpiling. I like using import and default parameters and the like, and so was hoping to get their usage on the server-side as well.

Comment: So, just use transpiling and not webpacking.  You don't have to use webpacking in order to get transpiling at all.  Many people transpile code without web pack.

Comment: So you're specifically interested in using ES modules in Node.js on the server side? That's the main goal here?

Comment: @jfriend00 It's true, I will attempt to use babel on its own to achieve the transpile. I just thought it would be nice to have one command to set it all in motion. The odd thing, is that the transpiled express code works on its own, but when wrapped in the webpack scaffolding (where it brings in my local requires but not the node_module requires) it gives me that error.

Comment: Webpacking your server.js can be necessary in some cases like React server side rendering and is currently a best practice in many React universal bootstrappers / starter kits.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with webpacked Express and this fixed it:
`response.sendFile(path.resolve('./public/index.html'), err => err && next(err));`

In my case the server.js and server.bundle.js files are in the root folder of my project.

If that's different in your case you can try:

`response.sendFile(path.resolve('./public/index.html'), { root: __dirname }, err => err && next(err));`